# Subversive Connector Discovery error

Tags: eclipse, svn

Trying to install Subversive for the first time.

Successfully installed Subversive "Team Provider" via the *Available Sites* dialog in Help >> Install New Software.  Added a site that points to the Helios Update Site.

Restarted Eclipse and tried to open the SVN Repository Browser and it automatically launched a **Subversive Connector Discovery** dialog, presenting me with 6 or 7 connectors to choose from.

I've tried every single one, and they all fail, stating that an "error occured" and that I need to check the "error log" (Eclipse error log?) for details.

I then exited the dialog and noticed that I can now view all the SVN-related perspective panes.

(1) Was it alright for me to cancel that Connector Discovery process, or will I need that to create/edit repositories locally? If I need it, what was going wrong and does anyone have any ideas for how to get it working?

(2) I'm trying to undertand the SVN Repositories feature for creating a new repository.  How do I point it to my local SVN server instance? The default is to query me for a URL that I assume I would point to one of those "publicly available" repos.... which I don't want!

Thanks for any and all help here!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem as Zac. 
I am trying to install on a new computer, and back in Oct it worked fine.
Now the install of the connectors does not work.

You and jmort253 are talking about 2 different things. 
Eclipse to work with SVN needs both the plugin and the connectors. 
Without the connectors installed, the SVN plugin alone won't work.

The site for the connectors seems to be: 
community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/

but looking at the list of available connectors with the names, 
it looks cutout, could there be a typo?

My last install already has a version newer than what the Subversive Connector Discovery proposes!

I downloaded the file needed directly to my harddrive. 
Now, how do I install? 
Simply putting it into dropins and restarting Eclipse did not work.

Best,

[edit] Problem solved!!

The regular Helios site leads to using connectors that do not work. 
So instead of using the info under the heading Helios in: 
www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php

I enabled in Eclipse to search for the link under Early Access:

Early Access
Version: 0.7.9.I20101203-1700 | Date: 03 December 2010 
Development build which includes latest changes. 
Update site: 
 http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/

Installing this version of SVN plugin: 0.7.9.I20101203-1700
then Subversive Connector Discovery find the latest connectors 
and everything installs fine.

Best,

Answer (score -5):

You need to first create a repository on a Subversion Server.  Until you learn more about the inner workings of how to setup a Subversion server, I suggest you get yourself a free SVN repository at http://assembla.com

Once you're more familiar, then you can maybe think about setting up your own Subversion server should you choose to do so.

Comment: So the Subversive Connector Discovery Tool **will not** work unless you've already set up a repo?!?! That doesn't really make sense: to not be able to install a tool until you've already used that tool! I don't want to use assembla.com or any other public repo; I'm trying to learn this stuff from the ground up, so if it takes me a week to set up a SVN server then so be it, I just want to do it myself!

Comment: Fair enough.  This is just one of many possible solutions.  From my experience, I've found that I personally solve problems better when I can break them up into usable chunks, but every person is different.  Good luck! :)